# Receive RESTClient POST JSON-Body in C# mvc and convert it to usable Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, http, post

I have a C# Website and Web API combined and a Mobile Android App. In the Mobile Android App I want to send a HttpPost with an `List<Integer>`, `List<Double>` and `long` to the C# Web API and in the C# Web API I want to convert those back to `List<int>`, `List<decimal>` and `long`.

The sending part from the Android App was done quite fast, since I've done this before. But at the receiving C# Web API end I'm having (a lot) of trouble.

In one of the Web API Controllers I've added the following method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("save")]
public bool SaveOrders([FromBody] STILL_UNDETERMINED parameter)
{
    // TODO: Convert given parameter to usable List<int>, List<decimal> and long
}
```

Right now I'm using the FireFox' RESTClient Plug-in to send these HttpPOSTs:

```
Method:   POST   http://localhost:54408/api/orders/save
Header:   Content-Type   application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body:     {"newPrices":[0.4,7.4],"productIds":[20,25],"dateInTicks":1402459200000}
```

I do end up in the method above and can debug it, but now I need to convert it to the List, List and long.

So, my question(s):

**What parameter should I use for the method?** I've tried:

- `string` (which is always null);
- `JObject` (which replaces all `[` for `:" {"` for some unknown reason, resulting in: `{ "{\"newPrices\":": { "0.4,7.4],\"productIds\":": { "20,25],\"dateInTicks\":1402459200000}": "" } } }`;
- and `dynamic` (which I can't do anything with since it's converter to an seemingly empty `object`)

**How should I convert this parameter to a `List<int>`, `List<decimal>` and `long`?**

- I've tried creating an custom Object (see below) and use all kind of different method to fill them, to many to list all here, all without a result (mainly because the parameter is already wrong):

Custom Object:

```
Data
{
       public List<int> productIds { get; set; }
       public List<decimal> newPrices { get; set; }
       public long dateInTicks { get; set; }
}
```

In theory it seems so simple:

- Send a HttpPOST from the FireFox' RESTClient plug-in
- Have a method in the API Controller that receives it (this already took quite some time and had to make some changes to MapHttpRoutes by using `actions`).
- Convert the paramater you receive from the Body to usable data (the part I'm stuck on right now..)

It seemed so simple, yet I can't get it to work in C#.. In Java I would have made this in less than 30 min and I can find a lot useful answers by Google-ing, but when I Google for C# HttpPOSTs I only get results to either send HttpPOSTs from C#, or read the response from the Stream AFTER sending the HttpPOST.. Nothing about just receiving JSON-body of a HttpPOST from a `[HttpPost]` method in C# mvc..

PS: I have the following in my Config file to only receive JSON format responses, maybe something is wrong with that.

```
// Only allow JSON response format
var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When posting JSON data to an MVC Action your need to specify the `Content-Type` header to be `application/json`. If you don't the model will always be null if you pass anything but a standard form collection.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ActionName("save")]
public bool SaveOrders(Data model)
{
   //model is populated, and you have access to ModelState
}

public class Data
{
    // the JSON to Model mapper match is case-insensitive
    public List<int> ProductIds { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> NewPrices { get; set; }
    public long DateInTicks { get; set; }
}
```

Post Data:

```
{"newPrices":[0.4,7.4],"productIds":[20,25],"dateInTicks":1402459200000}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you should be able to pass it in as a model object.  First setup your model class:

```
public class Order
{
    public List<int> productIds { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> newPrices { get; set; }
    public long dateInTicks { get; set; }
}
```

Then setup your action to use the model to bind to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveOrders(Order order)
{
    //TODO: Save...
}
```

Then all you have to do is make sure you send it in as a JSON object that matches your Order model. So the post values would be ["productIds"], ["newPrices"] and so on, and it'll automatically populate the order parameter on SaveOrders.  This gives a good idea on how these things bind up:

http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/asp-net-mvc-2-model-binding-for-a-collection

Comment: You also have to specify the `Content-Type` header to be `application/json` to get this to work with JSON data instead of a standard POST.

Comment: @siva.k Thanks you so much! This was exactly the problem. I used `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`. If you want you can make an answer out of it I can accept, or should I make the answer myself crediting you? Your call.